# If $g(z)$ is analytic near $0$, and $g(z) = \exp(z\,g(z))$, then $g(z)=\sum_{n \geq 0}\frac{(n+1)^{n-1}}{n!} z^n$ near $0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analytic-functions

This is a question from the article "An Occupancy Discipline and Applications".

> $g(z)$ is an analytic function near $0$. Suppose
> $$g(z) = \exp(z\,g(z))$$
> Then prove that, near $z=0$,
> $$g(z) = \sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{(n+1)^{n-1}}{n!} z^n$$

I have tried to read the reference "Solution of the equation ze^z = a", but I can not find a solution for this equation.

Comment: Do you know about [Cayley's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_formula)? Basically, the equation $g = \exp(zg)$ says that a rooted tree can be uniquely written by marking its root ($z$ term) and then looking at the trees grafted at the root (this is what $\exp$ is accomplishing). Thus, the coefficients for $g$ follow the unique recursion that counts rooted trees, and Cayley's formula gives you the closed form.

Comment: Solution of $g=\exp(zg)$ is $g=\frac{-W(-z)}{z}$ in terms of the Lambert W function.  Your series is correct.

Comment: This is the first time I learn Lambert W function. I have checked its property. Thanks. I don't know Cayley's formula. But Lambert W function solves this equation.